# Why does this iFrame work on one page, but not another?

Tags: iframe, vimeo

I am trying to load a vimeo video into a page, but it is telling me:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

but on other pages the same iframe, copied and pasted, works fine.

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4426465" width="400" height="230" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: What are the pages? can you post them please.

Comment: they are offline for testing, so not at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe vimeo verifies the "Referer" HTTP header and disallows embedding video on certain websites?

Comment: they are both on the same, localhost, domain